# Infinite Allowance for token inside smart contract?

Tags: allowance

I want contract2 to be able to transfer the tokens from contract1.

So i set allowance to -1

If i understand correctly it's not "infinite", but it's the highest possible number in EVM.

My question is... Do i need to create a function inside the contract that will reset the allowance back to -1? As users interact with the contract, could they drain the allowance to 0 and render the contract useless?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, except if the token contract has a malicious approve() function that allows for an adversary to set approval arbitrarily, I don't see how that's an issue, as _allowance is always checked against _msgSender(), which is the signer that called the token contract.

Comment: User deposits tokens into Contract1. And Contract2 transfers the tokens from Contract1 to itself.

User must give allowance to Contract1, but Contract2 then takes those tokens, so when launching Contract1, i set allowance to -1 for Contract2.

The question is now... Do i need to add a function that will "reset" allowance to -1 again?